# How to alter the time in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I wanted to change the minutes/hours of pythonic time.
I have a string of time `start_time = "2013-09-30 14:12:08.024923"`. I want it to convert it to its ceil quater,half or full time, ie if I set interval as `15` I should get `2013-09-30 14:15:00.0000`. If interval is `30`, I should get `2013-09-30 14:15:00.0000`

How can I change it?

Here is what I have tried.

```
start_time = "2013-09-30 14:12:08.024923"
start_time  = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
interval = 15
ceil_to = (start_time.minute/interval) *interval + interval

start_time.minute = interval # throws error saying attribute 'minute' of 'datetime.datetime' objects is not writable
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: That's why came to SO. :P

Comment: You're missing some lines in your example code: specifically the lines where you turn `start_time` from a string to a `datetime` object.

Comment: Oops sorry. Typo. Forgot to include that line. Updated.

Comment: You seem to be getting the same result regardless of interval ... is that what you meant?

Comment: @mgilson: I'm guessing the issue is that one can't change the `start_time.minute` fied

Comment: If everything else is right, then `datetime.replace` should do the trick ...

Comment: @mgilson: If it matters to you, I'd already typed my answer before seeing your comment

Comment: @nhgrif When I do this, `from delorean import fluxcapacitor; fluxcapacitor.gottaGoBackInTime("1955-11-05")` I get this error: `FluxCapacitorError: Not enough jigawatts`

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- I figured that -- But it really doesn't matter to me any way :).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this with `replace`:

```
start_time = start_time.replace(minute=ceil_to, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Comment: I tried this. `start_time = start_time.replace(minute=ceit_to,second = 0 )`. This yielded me `2013-09-30 14:15:00.024923`. How do I replace milliseconds with `0`

Comment: @user1162512, `.replace(minute=ceil_to, second=0, microsecond=0)`